# WPF Grid & Collapsed Content

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I've Got a Window with this basic layout:

```
<Window
    MinHeight="72" MaxHeight="400" Height="Auto"
    MinWidth="460" MaxWidth="460">
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            ...
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0" MaxHeight="40" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Header -->
            </StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{My Fancy Binding To collapse this}" ... />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{My Fancy Binding To collapse this}" ... />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

What im trying to achieve is a window that's compact when the Two TextBlock's at the bottom are Visibility="Collapsed", and expands up to a max height set when they're not.

This works quite alright for the `<Grid>` but it seems that no matter how i re-arrange my layout, i can't get the window to attempt to use the minimum space, it always sits at max-size with a lot of useless whitespace.

**What is happening:**

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Header                            |
+-----------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
| Wasted Space I want to            |
| "collapse"                        |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
| Footer                            |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**What I want:**

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Header                            |
+-----------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------+
| Footer                            |
+-----------------------------------+

Or Effectively:

+-----------------------------------+
| Header                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| Footer                            |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you wanting the window to resize? or just the layout to be compacted inside the window?

Comment: @Metro Smurf I dont want the user to resize the window, I want to be able to "Collapse" some content in the window and have it's visual space removed from the dialog (thus shortening it's overall height).

Comment: Right, so you want to resize the window. Check the SizeToContent property on the Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is SizeToContent="Height" on the Window.

Comment: Thankyou so much :) This is what I needed, silly little property lost in a sea of intellisense.